# Tanh activation function outputs the same value for any given input in a Deep Reinforcement Learning

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

Basically im working on the DDPG algorithm in DRL where i have an actor and critic networks.

The actor network architecture is quite simple:

```
1. Input layer contains 22 neurons that represents the state values (ranging from 0.1 to 10.0 max not normalizing them)

2. Two hidden layers with 128 neurons, with Leaky Relu activation (alpha = 0.01), and with HeUniform kernel initializer

3. Output layer with a single neuron has tanh activation, using Glorot kernel initializer
```

The critic network has the same architecture but we only concatenate the 22 state values with the action produced by the actor, the only difference is the ouput of the critic has no activation. And both networks use Adam.

The problem arises when the training starts because i run a few steps without actually start the learning, but when the learning starts, the actor converges quickly to output values 1 or -1 afor any given input.

I tried many learning rates for both actor and critic. One thing to note is when i set the actor learning rate to 1e-5 and the critic to 1e-3 the networks sometimes converges quickly, sometimes it takes longer to converge and sometimes it does not converge.

Same thing when tried BatchNorm layers, Relu activation instead of Leaky Relu, different weight initializers.

The base hyperparameters are:
Replay buffer size: 1000000
Batch size: 128
Discount factor: 0.95
Tau (soft update factor): 0.002

Comment: What is the actual range of your environment actions? Does this match the use of the tanh activation in the actor?